# add null value to a query where rows doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    nullif(((ad != 3 and ad !=9 and ad !=2) + 
        (rg != 3 and rg !=9 and rg !=2) + 
        (sr != 3 and sr !=9 and sr !=2) + 
        (cm != 3 and cm !=9 and cm !=2) + 
        (ba != 3 and ba !=9 and ba !=2) + 
        (jt != 3 and jt !=9 and jt !=2) + 
        (sg != 3 and sg !=9 and sg !=2)),0) as dia
FROM
    asistencia
where
    id > 181 and id < 213
```

I already add null if the value is 0,  but let's say the table rows id ends at 200

So, the result query only shows the value rows until row id 200. I want to show complete rows from 181 up to 213 adding null value to rows beyond row id 200
is that possible?

This is because I want to show all days in a Highcharts chart.

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Have you tried setting `xAxis.max` option?: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max